# 公開秘密鍵ペアの使い方

Tags: security, ssh

プログラムでないので恐縮ですが、プログラム開発関連ってことですみません。
サーバーなどにSSHで接続する場合、公開鍵秘密鍵ペアを作成したりしますが、

- 接続先ごとにペアを作成した方がよいのか？
- その場合など鍵のファイル名を変更するべきか？

という一般的というか、通常の使い方がわかりません。
ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

接続先毎に公開鍵秘密鍵ペアを作る必要はありません。

通常は接続元毎に公開鍵秘密鍵ペアを作ります。作った秘密鍵は接続元に置いておき、公開鍵を接続先に配布します。

また例外的に、接続先毎に秘密鍵を変えたい場合には、 ~/.ssh ディレクトリ内に (デフォルトの id_rsa とは異なる) 別名で保存しておき、ssh 接続のたびに `-i` オプションで秘密鍵のファイルを指定するか、[~/.ssh/config](http://nauthiz.hatenablog.com/entry/20100919/1284892108) で接続先毎に利用する秘密鍵を指定します。

余談ではありますが、1つの秘密鍵を複数の接続元へ配布して再利用する、という使い方はセキュリティ上あまり褒められませんので、可能ならば避けたほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: 実例教えていただいてすごく助かります。

接続先ごとではく、接続元ごとということですか。。。
デスクトップMacとノートMacの２台を持っていたときに、
接続先が複数３つA,B,Cあったとして、
鍵ペアですからクライアントごとに１ペアを作り、
公開鍵を接続先A,B,Cに「兼用」で使用する
ってことでしょうか？

接続先A,B,Cそれぞれは、接続元クライアントごとの公開鍵を２つ登録され利用される

ということでしょうか？

Comment: クライアント２つとも利用するのが自分だから、鍵ペアもコピーして同じものを利用したほうが良いですかね？

Comment: 「 クライアントごとに１ペアを作り、公開鍵を接続先A,B,Cに「兼用」で使用する ってことでしょうか？」

この理解であっています。

Comment: とても実務での使用方法を教えていただきよく理解できました、ありがとうございました。